# PHP syntax error: WordPress function count_user_posts_by_type from WordPress Codex

Tags: php, wordpress, count, posts

I'm trying to use the following function from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts

```
function count_user_posts_by_type($userid, $post_type='post') {
  global $wpdb;
  $where = get_posts_by_author_sql($post_type, TRUE, $userid);
  $count = $wpdb->get_var( \"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where\" );
  return apply_filters('get_usernumposts', $count, $userid);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING in .../wp-content/themes/aa/functions.php on line 106
```

In my template I tried using it two ways:

```
$authorcount = count_user_posts_by_type($author->ID, 'videos');
```

and

```
$authorcount = count_user_posts_by_type($author->ID, $post_type='videos');
```

Can anyone point out what the syntax error is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe line 106 is this

```
  $count = $wpdb->get_var( \"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where\" );
```

Because there's an obvious syntax error. It should be like this:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->posts} $where" );
```